# How can i use same column for different content type types , to be readonly in one and not readonly in other

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a case where i need to use same field (column) for 2 different content types. In one content type i wish the field to be read only and in the other not.

The xml of the field is readonly = true. I tried to use in the content type the attribute readonly = false , but in this case it won't display the field. The field is hidden .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that once you set the field to ReadOnly it is hidden from New and Edit Forms.

The only way to make it readonly is using either of two codes below :

```
$("input[title='Title']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Or

```
$("input[title='FieldName']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
```